# How return value from two nested jquery methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, return

I'm trying to update global variable inside jquery method .on(), but I can't figure out how to return this updated value to global scope, which will overwrite this global variable. The problem is that the .on() method is inside .each() method. So there is two callback functions to break out. Below my sample code:

```
var globalValue = 0;

$('.container').each(function() {
  $(this).on('mousemove', function() {
    globalValue = 1;
    return globalValue;
  });
  return globalValue;
});
console.log(globalValue);  // prints 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return a value like you're trying to from an event handler.  The event handler occurs sometime later and when it is called, it is called by the system and thus returning a value just goes into jQuery and then back to the system.

You can set a global variable from an event handler.  But even that it typically not a desired solution.  Usually, if you calclulate something from an event handler, you either use it right in the event handler or you call some other function and pass the calculated variable to the other function.

FYI, the `.each()` is not needed in your code as the `.on()` method will automatically be applied to all the DOM elements in `$('.container')`. You could just do this:

```
var globalValue = 0;

$('.container').on('mousemove', function() {
    // set global variable
    globalValue = 1;
});
```

but this is generally more useful:

```
$('.container').on('mousemove', function() {
    var localValue = 1;
    myfunction(localValue);
});
```